# Holder's inequality and an infinite series question

Tags: measure-theory

I'm looking at a sample measure theory exam question.

(a) State Holder's Inequality

(b) Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers and let $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ be such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^{2-\epsilon}<\infty$$

Show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt n} <\infty$$

Any ideas how to begin?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try applying Holder's inequality with $p:=2-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Holders inequality with $p$ and $q$ depending on $\epsilon$. The two functions you split up are $a_n$ and $1/\sqrt n$. Ask yourself, when will $\Sigma (1/\sqrt{n})^q$ converge? For which of these values will the other sum converge?